# How to use a global array in multiple modules

Tags: c, arrays, header-files, extern

I'm trying to access the programs array in my main file. It is declared in the header file and initialized in a separate module called fileReader. The error message I receive is

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_programs", referenced from:
      _main in test-0bf1e8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "header.h"
#include "fileReader.c"

int main() {

    readPrograms();
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        printf("%s", programs[i]);
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

fileReader.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "header.h"

int readPrograms() {
    int i=0;
    int numProgs=0;
    char* programs[50];
    char line[50];

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("files.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)!=NULL) {
        //add each filename into array of programs
        programs[i]=strdup(line); 
        i++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

header.h

```
extern char* programs[];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have a global array. You need to create one if you want to use it in one module, let alone multiple modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to include C files from other C files, only the header files.

Here is what you need to fix:

- Add a prototype of `readPrograms` function to the `header.h`
- Remove `#include "fileReader.c"` from the main.c file
- Add a *definition* of `programs` array to one of your C files (say, main.c).
- Remove declaration of the local `programs` from `readPrograms`

The definition of `programs` that you put in main.c should look like this:

```
char* programs[50];
```

You can put it before or after your `main()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm still getting the error message after making all of those changes. is the prototype just a line in the header file like so? int readPrograms();

Comment: @user3192682 Yes, that's the prototype. What errors do you get after making the changes?

Comment: the same error that I was receiving originally, it is posted above

Comment: @user3192682 I just tried compiling this, it compiles perfectly. I made exactly the four changes that I described in the answer, and compiled the code like this: `gcc main.c fileReader.c`. I got `a.out` which reads from `files.txt`, and prints the first four strings.

Comment: @user3192682 Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Q3HB4JCr) with your code. Comments show the names of files. I think you missed step #3, adding a definition. It's on line 23 of the pastebin.

Comment: Ahh thanks so much. I wasn't aware the definition had to be outside of the main function, could you possibly explain why? Thanks again, it is working fine now.

Comment: @user3192682 Definitions inside functions are local to the functions in which they are declared. If you want an `extern` variable, it needs to be defined at the scope of a translation unit, which is a geek speak for "outside any function".